# D3: Difference between layout.force & forceSimulation to build network graph

Tags: d3.js, d3-force-directed

I am a beginner of D3 and was trying to grasp the ropes on how to build a proper force-directed graph in D3. There appear to be two different ways to build it.

1. Using layout.force. [e.g](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1129492)
2. Using forceSimulation. [e.g](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045)

I'm more or less comfortable with the first as the code is shorter and easier to understand. However, it is hard to translate functions from one sample codes using example 2 to example 1 without a proper understanding. Would anyone be able to describe the advantages or disadvantages for each?

Thank you.

Comment: It's due to changes in namespace from v3 to v4. From docs on changes in v4 from v3: "The force layout d3.layout.force has been renamed to d3.forceSimulation." [link](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#forces-d3-force)